# Concatenated Domain Name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've taken over the development of a project and have noticed a weird snippet in the JavaScript where the developer wrote the following:

```
/* ... code */

var el = document.getElementById('foo');

el.href = "http://" + "w" + "w" + "w" + "." + "d" + "o" + "main.com/foobar/";

/* ... code */
```

I have some hunches as to what the purpose is, but will refrain from expressing it so as to not misguide, probably better, answers ...

***What is the purpose of concatenating the domain?***

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @Curiosity: You should probably clearly state within your "question", what is really your actual question.

Comment: just added it in bold. i guess it wasn't obvious enough ...

Comment: Not sure why someone would use a picture of a Playboy Playmate as their icon either. Well I have some hunches, but I'll refrain from expressing them in case they affect your own opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of JavaScript itself, this has practically no effect - the result is the same.

But the reason may be different than to accomplish some task in JavaScript. I guess there are two possibilities that are most likely to be the case here:

1. To **mislead other programmers** (so the domain name is not easily found by simple text search). Similar (but a lot more complex) ways are used by worms to insert code into the website without showing what it contains, unless you will put a lot more effort to analyse it.
2. To try to **mislead crawlers**, which probably assumes they are not parsing the JavaScript and getting actual result. It may be the case for example if the programmer feared that the code will be eg. indexed and by searching this domain name in the search engine, anyone can find out it was mentioned in the code of the site you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Well normally you would be concatenating this because you would use variables within it...

```
el.href = "http://www." + domain + "." + ext "/" + additionalUrl;
```

Otherwise separating letter by letter like that serves no purpose. I'm assuming the previous programmer was just bored :)